# FLV not playing within two SWF files

Tags: flash, flvplayback, flash-cs5.5

Before I start off; I'm not a pro at Flash at all.

Folder structure:

- start.swf
- assets/moviecontainer.swf
- assets/flv/movie.flv

What I want is to open start.swf, have it embed moviecontainer.swf which has a FLV playback object that loads in the movie.flv.

When I check my moviecontainer.swf, it runs properly.
But when I use start.swf it loads moviecontainer.swf (because I can see it has the background and all) but the movie won't play (and I think the buttons don't work anymore)

I have saved both .swfs with the "Local files only" option. I have no idea what the problem can be, as I said, I'm no Flash pro and I have no experience as to say "oh it looks like we got that xyz problem.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a path issue:

When you set the url for the FLV playback component from within the movie container and run it, the application's working directory is `assets`, and the movie's relative path is `flv/movie.flv`.

When you import the container into your start.swf, the work path has changed to the top directory, and the url should now be `assets/flv/movie.flv`.

Comment: Yes, this crossed my mind.. but my interpretation was that the path within the 'second' swf is correct.. it shouldn't matter for the first one. But I'll give it a try!

Comment: I *does* matter. You could pass a work path variable from your top movie to nested swfs (which is set to the folder the swf is located in) and prepend it to all URLs, then you'd have a solution that always works.